# connection string for SQL database by path For Desktop Application

Tags: .net

I want a Connect .mdf file by path as we can do for Access db file

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Best place to find [Connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/)

Comment: So there is any way to connect without reference of server..?

Comment: not sure , i think you need some kind of sql server to read it , and sql express or similar